# Visual Studio Compiler Errors disappeared

Tags: visual-studio

I somehow lost my visual studio settings file and now when I try to compile the project I am only shown the command line output, it used to show me a nice table of the Error#, Error Message and Line number. I haven't been able to find any setting to enable this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should show it again.

**Tools** -> **Options** -> **Projects and Solutions** -> **General**

Select "Always show Error List if build finishes with errors"